# Flutter with AdMob banner persistence through entire app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, admob, banner, flutter-navigation

I need to have an admob banner on top my Flutter app visible at all times AND not have to care about it being visible after I shuffle my app's pages.
I don't want to touch it, reload on page change, recreate it and so on - waste of time.

So far it's been over a year that I've made it work with two MaterialApps nested inside one another - one parent with SafeArea (banner goes in there) and the second one is where the app actually "lives" and goes about navigating its pages with cool transition effects and so on.

Before telling me how wrong it is - it WORKS. In production app serving thousands of people daily. Zero problems so far.

However, I'd like to know, with all the recent Flutter updates and stuff, maybe there's finally a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to wrap your `MaterialApp` inside a `Column` where you put the ad widget on top and place the `MaterialApp` underneath inside an `Expanded`?

Comment: @tmaihoff I've experimented with this be4, it leads to other problems with rendering when you have complex screens in your app

Comment: Hi @galloper, I just started Flutter and I also have the same problem. I tried to use the double MaterialApp as you proposed and managed to view it, but when I call the AppBar in the nested MaterialApp it creates another upper space (like a SafeArea, but in this case it seems useless). I'm afraid I'm messing with the spaces, could you please post the code that allowed you to use the banner with the double MaterialApp?
Maybe it could also be useful for those who want to help us find a better solution (if any).